# Setting origin identity (e.g request.auth.user) from upstream proxy header value?

Tags: istio

our istio ingressgateway is only reachable via an authenticating reverse proxy. That proxy adds headers for the authenticated user (but no JWT).

Is it possible to configure istio to use this header for the origin identity?

If I understand istio correctly, what I'm looking for is setting the request.auth.user field in a filter(?) to a header value from the incoming request. Basically the opposite of this: https://discuss.istio.io/t/question-decode-jwt-and-put-sub-into-a-request-header/1213

Comment: I think this [link](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/control-headers/) could be helpful. If we talk about filter, it's called [Envoy Filter](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/lua_filter) and language used here is lua, so it might be hard to actually make it, but it actually could work. Based on istio [doc](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/security/istio.authentication.v1alpha1/#OriginAuthenticationMethod) `Currently, only JWT is supported for origin authentication.` Let me know if this answer your question

Comment: @jt97 I know I can route based on the header but I need to set the origin identity to use policies for enforcement. But yeah setting request.auth.user in a lua envoy filter would work. Is that possible?

Comment: Found some things in envoy [doc](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/lua_filter#currently-supported-high-level-features), `Inspection of headers`, `For example, a script could make an upstream HTTP call for authentication, and then directly respond with a 403 response code.` So I think it should be possible to do.